# by using vue-property-decorator and vuex-module-decorators, I am not able to access state inside grandchild component. How to do that?

Tags: vue.js

by using vue-property-decorator and vuex-module-decorators, I am not able to access state inside grandchild component.

here is explanation:

I have a root component inside that I have a direct child component, In this child component which is grandchild of the root component, I am accessing one of the state's properties this state's property is being consoled as "undefined", why so?

root coponent: TodoApp
direct child : TodoInput
grandchild :  TodoSummary

**on TodoSummary's rendering state properties are consoled as undefined why so?**

Comment: Please, don't describe your code but post it. Currently you're the only person who saw it.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  Was it different without decorators? It's possible that you're focusing on wrong thing and the problem is in a store.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.